# How do I use nextRow variable (next open row in a spreadsheet) as a variable and then ".copy" something into it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ERP-system that copies information from a delivery-note into an archive. My problem is that I can't find a way to declare the code to find the next available row (where the data is going to be stored) as a variable and then copy the data over, I can only do it without variables.

I have tried to dim and not dim the code for next available row and tried with the cell that the data is being copied from as a variable and not.

I have also tried declaring the cell where the data is being copied from as an variable (shipFrom) and then copy shipFrom into the next available row without declaring that as a variable, still not doing anything.

Code:

```
Dim nextRow As Range
Dim shipFrom As String
shipFrom = Sheets("DN").Range("D9").value
Set nextRow = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

shipFrom.Copy nextRow
```

No error message just no result when running the code...
I excpect the value from D9 which is declared as shipFrom to copy over to nextRow which is the variable I used for the next available row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to declare `shipFrom As Range`
2. and use `Set shipFrom` to set the range to it.

Because you cannot use `.Copy` on a string. It only works on a range object.

```
Dim shipFrom As Range
Set shipFrom = Sheets("DN").Range("D9")

Dim nextRow As Range
Set nextRow = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

shipFrom.Copy nextRow 'copy the whole cell shipFrom to nextRow
```

Note that `.Copy` copies the whole cell with all it's formattings. An alternative to copy only the value would be

```
Dim shipFrom As String
shipFrom = Sheets("DN").Range("D9").Value

Dim nextRow As Range
Set nextRow = Sheets("Arkiv").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

nextRow.Value = shipFrom 'set the value of nextRow equal to the value shipFrom
```